# writing content of local file to blob using javascript

Tags: blob

I am trying to upload an excel file(named test1.xls) present in my computer in c drive at location->C:\test\test1.xls to google site(https://sites.google.com/xyz).To do so, I am using Google script editor and code shown below. The issue is that I am not able to pass the contents of file test1.txt at location C:\test\test1.txt instead of the text ("Here is some data")shown in code line shown below(var blob = Utilities.newBlob("Here is some data", "text/plain", "test1.xls");).Also what needs to be given instead of "text/plain" as it is excel file.Please let me know how to do that with code as I am new to google scripting/api coding,many thanks in advance.

CODE->

```
function doPost(e) {
var site = SitesApp.getSiteByUrl("https://sites.google.com/xyz"); Logger.log(site.getName()); 

 var page = site.getChildren()[0];

 // Create a new blob and attach it. Many useful functions also return
 // blobs file uploads, URLFetch
 var blob = Utilities.newBlob("Here is some data", "text/plain", "test1.xls");

try {
 // Note that the filename must be unique or this call will fail

 page.addHostedAttachment(blob);
 }
  catch(e){
    Logger.log('Hosted attachment error msg:' +e.message);
    }
  }
```

Comment: It is an urgent requirement, so request for prompt response if anyone knows how to do this..many thanks in advance.